# angular-devkit css error. optimize-css-webpack-plugin.js

Tags: c#, css, .net, angular, single-page-application

I'm attempting to run `ng build --prod` in my SPA terminal. I get the error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: styles.8275e44a6546337b4b89.css Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element..
```

along with an error log file.

The error log file states there is an error in the optimize-css-webpack-plugin.js file.

I have reinstalled the devkit and tried to update the angular version. Still doesn't work. Does anyone know what's going on here?

[image: Log screenshot]

[image: optimize-css-webpack-plugin.js screenshot]